# Access iTunes shares from Rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox, itunes, daap

Its a bit of a tease that I can see iTunes shares on the local network in Rhythmbox, but I'm unable to access them. Is there anything I can do to enable access to function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with iTunes 7 Apple started encrypting access to [DAAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Audio_Access_Protocol) to stop this kind of feature. Unfortunately there's not much application developers can do.

Here's a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/amarok/+bug/62842) in Ubuntu with information.

Some players (such as Banshee) have an informational page explaining to the user why it can't connect. [Filing a bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) on rhythmbox to explain why it can't connect would probably be prudent so it doesn't just give you an inexplicable error.

Comment: Its unfortunate that Rhythmbox will still display these shares even though it cannot access them. Hopefully they address this at some point.

Comment: Interesting. Do you know if iTunes has some technical innovation preventing its encryption from being reverse engineered or is it just lack of developer time and resources available for Rhythmbox and similar projects?

Answer (score 4):

You have 4 options:

1. Switch to a version of iTunes older than 7
2. Complain to Apple
3. Spend a few years with some mathematicians and destroy modern theories of cryptography
4. Steal Apple's encryption key

What's going on is that Apple added strong public key encryption to iTunes to prevent interoperability with everything that's not iTunes.  It's Apple, expect no less.

Comment: #4 is probably the easiest but wouldn't be allowed to be distributed in the US (and some other places).

Comment: #5: stop using Apple products ? Ok, that's hardly a solution to the question, but if Apple doesn't want to let you use their product the way you want, why give them publicity/money/etc ?

Comment: Little Jawa, that sounds like the best solution!

Answer (score 1):

One additional option is to run a separate DAAP streaming server on that computer. It's possible to install and set up mt-daapd (or forked-daapd, but I think that has dependency issues on recent OSXes) and point it at your itunes music library.  You would then have 2 streams - the one provided by iTunes and the one provided by mt-daapd - make sure to give them different names so you can tell them apart from your music client.

Here's some detailed instructions:
http://zettelchen.blogspot.ca/2010/01/firefly-mt-daapd-with-external-drive.html

Answer (score -1):

Sync your files with Amazon Cloud Player.  Yes, you might need to buy some gigs of storage, but once you upload them they sync and they are effectively laundered.  I haven't use I tunes once I was freed by Linux, I won't ever use I-tunes again! Catch 22 I did it with windows, I don't know if Amazon's cloud player has an app for Ubuntu!